# A tarefa "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" não foi carregada do assembly

Tags: c#, xamarin

Esse é o erro que estou pegando:

> C:\meu_caminho\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.0.122203\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll.
>   Confirme se a declaração  está correta, se o assembly e
>   todas as suas dependências estão disponíveis e se a  tarefa contém uma
>   classe pública que implementa Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Abaixo o código fonte do xaml.cs

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        public  void Login_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginService svc = new LoginService();
            LoginRS res = svc.Login(txtUsuario.Text, txtSenha.Text);
            if (res != null && res.Success  )
            {
                App.LooggedUser = res;

                Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
            }
            else if(res != null && ! res.Success)
            {
                lblErroLogin.Text = res.Exception;
            }
            else
            {
                lblErroLogin.Text = "Não foi possível realizar o Login, por favor verifique sua conexão com a Internet";
            }
        }
    }
```

Antes estava dando o erro abaixo no InitializeComponent

> Unhandled Exception:  System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type
>   with token 01000043 (from typeref, class/assembly
>   Xamarin.Forms.Internals.ResourceLoader, Xamarin.Forms.Core,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null) ocorreu

Como faço para resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 2):

Erro MSB4062: a tarefa "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" não pôde ser carregada a partir do assembly

Olá.

Resolvi meu problema montando o projeto (arquivo-para-arquivo) e compilando e conseguindo acompanhar o problema.

Uma biblioteca de solução exigiu o pacote Microsoft.Bcl.Build no projeto que faz referência (a aplicação no meu caso).

Acabei de instalar o pacote via nuget e tudo está bem ...

Eu espero que isso ajude.

Answer (score 0):

Duas coisas indispensáveis para se fazer usando Xamarin em caso de problemas:

1. Limpe a solução.
2. Reinicie o Visual Studio.